# create dynamic number of components in react js

Tags: reactjs

if I have input field of numbers
and I want connect it with component
for example if I type number 2 in input field
the component render 2 times
and if type 3 in input field the component render 3 times
how can I do this in react js
example:
this is input :
and the user type number 3 for example in this input field

```
  <input type="number">
```

and this component created dynamically based on this number in input field
if it was 3 this paragraph created 3 times

```
class Hero extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return ( 
           <p> this paragraph</p>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Você pode classificar minha resposta como útil? ↑

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am Brazilian and therefore I speak Portuguese, but I will use the translator to try to help you.

What you can do is the following:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState([]);
  const [number, setNumber] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={number} onChange={({ target: t }) => setNumber(t.value)} />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          let newArray = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            newArray.push(i + 1);
          }
          setInputs(newArray);
        }}
      >
        Update
      </button>

      <div>
        <label>Inputs:</label>
        {inputs.map((n) => (
          <p> this paragraph {n}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: no I don't mean this , I edited the question so you can understand what I mean